# If there is an ArrayList, a mutable data structure with all the capabilities of a MutableList. Then why do we need MutableList?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, data-structures

```
val array = arrayListOf(1)
array.add(3)

val list = mutableListOf(1)
list.add(3)
```

Seems like this both data structures has the same methods and approaches. I don't understand then why do we need MutableList.

1. In which cases I need to use ArrayList and MutableList?
2. What data structure is MutableList implements? It's array or something different?

I already read official documentation. I learned a lot about arrays. But I don't understand difference between ArrayList and MutableList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `MutableList` is just an interface (similar to `List`, but with additional methods to modify its data), and `ArrayList` is one of its implementations.

As for the code from the question, both `mutableListOf(1)` and `arrayListOf(1)` create an `ArrayList` under the hood, but they have different return types, in accordance with their names – the former returns a mutable list as an interface, while the latter provides a specific implementation, i.e., `ArrayList`.

[image]

Regarding `val array = arrayListOf(1)`, it's not actually an array; it's still a list. The structure is called `ArrayList` simply because it uses an array in its internal implementation. If you want to create an array, you can use `arrayOf()` for everything but primitive types, and `intArrayOf()`, `floatArrayOf()`, etc. for the primitives.

Comment: Worth adding that the reason for the `MutableList` interface is that there are many different implementations you can choose from (such as `LinkedList`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, various anonymous ones, and many others in third-party libraries — all with different performance characteristics and/or additional features).  And if you write code which simply expects a `MutableList` implementation, then it will work unchanged with all of them!